# How are those vectors orthogonal?

Tags: inner-products, orthogonality

> [image]

I tried multiplying them and I got $-1 + 5i +i +5$ which means they are not orthogonal. could anyone help me in this?

Comment: try $x\cdot y = \sum x_i \overline{y_i}$

Comment: For complex spaces, the dot product requires you take the complex conjugate of one of those vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner product is $(2+3i)(1-i)+(-1+5i)(i)$ which is $0$.